# Генерация динамического URL

Tags: apache, dns, ddns

Не смог найти подобного вопроса, опишу кейс:

Сейчас у меня есть вебслужба которая работает и висит на определенном субдомене `service.domain.com`

Я бы хотел чтобы в идеале на основной странице `domain.com` была кнопка `service` и при клике на неё генерилась бы одноразовая ссылка на эту службу, т.е. человек кликает, и у него открывается новая вкладка `qwe123.domain.com` которая фактически отображает ему страницу со службой `service.domain.com` (но просто так по ней перейти нельзя)

Идея в том чтобы у конечных пользователей не было бы возможности зайти по одной и той же ссылке два раза. Одна ссылка - один сеанс работы. Как это технически возможно реализовать в плане настройки виртуальных хостов `Apache` настройка `*` DNS записей